# missing plugins: Sitecore.DataExchange.Plugins.SynchronizationSettings

Tags: data-exchange-framework

Using Sitecore DEF 2.01 in Sitecore 9, I'm following the [tutorial](http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/DataExchangeFramework/v2.0.1/cookbooks/custom-providers/implementing-a-provider/index.html) for the File based provider, with minor modifications to read that the file contains json, and so my value accessor contains a property name rather than an index.

Run I run the tenant, Im getting the error

> ERROR [Data Exchange] Pipeline context is missing at least one
>   required plugin. (pipeline: Experience from File to Item Sync
>   Pipeline, pipeline step: Resolve Experience Info Item, pipeline step
>   identifier: XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX, missing plugins:
>   Sitecore.DataExchange.Plugins.SynchronizationSettings)

Any ideas why based on the tutorial code?

My endpoint provider looks like:

```
   [SupportedIds(TextFileEndpointTemplateId)]
public class MulesoftEndpointConverter : BaseEndpointConverter
{
    public const string TextFileEndpointTemplateId = "{XXX-XXX}";
    public const string TemplateFieldPath = "Path";
    public MulesoftEndpointConverter(IItemModelRepository repository) : base(repository)
    {
    }
    protected override void AddPlugins(ItemModel source, Endpoint endpoint)
    {
        //create the plugin
        var settings = new MulesoftSettings
        {
            //
            //populate the plugin using values from the item
            Path = this.GetStringValue(source, TemplateFieldPath)
        };
        //
        //add the plugin to the endpoint
        endpoint.AddPlugin(settings);
    }
}
```

And the ReadConverter lile

```
    [SupportedIds(ReadTextFileStepTemplateId)]
public class ReadMulesoftConverter : BasePipelineStepConverter
{
    public const string ReadTextFileStepTemplateId = "{XXX-XXX}";
    public const string TemplateFieldEndpointFrom = "EndpointFrom";
    public ReadMulesoftConverter(IItemModelRepository repository) : base(repository)
    {
    }
    protected override void AddPlugins(ItemModel source, PipelineStep pipelineStep)
    {
        //
        //create the plugin
        var settings = new EndpointSettings
        {
            //populate the plugin using values from the item
            EndpointFrom = this.ConvertReferenceToModel<Endpoint>(source, TemplateFieldEndpointFrom)
        };
        //
        //add the plugin to the pipeline step
        pipelineStep.AddPlugin(settings);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see the problem is not here. It is in the "Resolve Experience Info Item" pipeline step and assigned pipeline step processor into it. Pipeline step processor requires "SynchronizationSettings" and it cannot find it. It means, no one from previous pipeline steps add "SynchronizationSettings" to a pipeline context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolve Experience Info Item** pipeline step requires ***SynchronizationSettings context*** plugin. But no one from previous pipeline steps add this plugin to the context.

It may happen if assigned pipeline step processor on **Resolve Experience Info Item** uses attribute or one of the base classes use:

```
[RequiredPipelineContextPlugins(typeof(SynchronizationSettings))]
```